# Custom post type is using the index.php template

Tags: custom-post-types, themes, templates

[Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) i read that if i create a custom post type, Wordpress will look to its specific template first, then it falls back to single.php.

I registered a custom post type (i'll show the taxonomy as well), which is properly shown in admin; i can create them well and i've been able to add them to the list of posts in blog's main page.
However, when i try to visit its page, i'm not getting a 404 error, but title is not shown in head section and it uses the index.php template, although i have a single.php which is working with common posts and i'd like to use. My new type (in functions.php)

```
function mytheme_customtypes () {
    $post_args = array(
        'label' => _('Blog Post'),
        'description' => _('Site\'s blog posts'),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('blog_posts'),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'thumbnail'),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'blog', 'has_archive' => 'blog_posts', 'with_front' => false)
    );

    $tax_args = array(
        'label' => 'Blog posts',
        'description' => _('Raccolta dei post per il blog'),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'blogs',  'with_front' => false),
        'hierarchical' => true
    );

    register_post_type('blog_post', $post_args);

    register_taxonomy('blog_posts', 'blog_post', $tax_args);
}
add_action('init', 'mytheme_customtypes');
```

Trying to create a new template name single-blog_post.php had no effect. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public` is `false` by default, your post type will not be visible on the front end without explicitly setting it to `true`.

```
$post_args = array(
    'public' => true,
    'label' => _('Blog Post'),
    'description' => _('Site\'s blog posts'),
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'taxonomies' => array('blog_posts'),
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'thumbnail'),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'blog', 'has_archive' => 'blog_posts', 'with_front' => false)
);
```

Comment: That's exactly what happened. Due to some lacks on my english, i thought that parameter would allow any wp user to edit it. Thanks, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I follow your question entirely (the bit about "adding" them to the blog). However from your description I think you are missing distinction between *archive* templates and *singular* templates.

`index.php` is catch–all template, it is last fallback for *both* archives and singular branches of hierarchy.

But before that the logic is different, roughly:

- `archive-blog_post.php` > `archive.php` > `index.php` for archive
- `single-blog_post.php` > `single.php` > `index.php` for singular

So if you are looking at *archive* of your CPT then any *singular* templates for it that you have are irrelevant. And other way around.

You would need to create *both* templates for your CPT if you want to customize *both* archives and singular entries for it.

Comment: Actually my problem is for singular post only. My wp is going straight to index.php template ignoring single.php and single-blog_post.php

Comment: Then it is not normal WP behavior and hard to guess without hands–on debug. Generally WP hierarchy just works, unless something messes it up or there are issues with set up (template files are not actually in expected place and such). Double check everything.

Comment: I'll try debugging, but i just think i did something wrong on my custom type setup